# Image Resolution - Important for SEO on Google?

Tags: seo, google-image-search

I typically set my image resolution for the web at 72 pixels/inch. Does Google look at image resolution as a ranking signal? Should I save my images at higher resolutions or does it not matter? The higher resolution images mean larger k sizes but I was not sure about what is acceptable.

Additional links I found helpful:

http://youtu.be/h2Zaj0CAUoU  (the most helpful)

http://youtu.be/Sj5Ny21q3oY

http://youtu.be/3NbuDpB_BTc

Comment: I think YES.. Because as suggested every where that Flash and other tools decrease SEO rate than I think it should be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different Search Engines have different criteria/Algo. For Image search but as far as `Google image search` is concerned

- I haven’t seen any such evidence that the resolution matters for a general image search, rather markup techniques (proper naming, right `alt` attribute ) plays a vital role.
- But the resolution/size of your image will matter when the user filters the image results through sizes `Large`, `Medium` `Icon` etc.

There is a lot of info about optimizing images for Google search, Just use Google itself to find a more detailed answer, I found few links below pretty helpful though not specific to Google but can give you fair idea about the whole process, you might want to have a look at these:

[Top 7 image optimization tips for SEO and site speed](http://zemalf.com/1373/image-optimization-tips/)

[How To Optimize Images For Search Engines…](http://www.seosmarty.com/image-seo/)

Answer (score 0):

72 dpi is standard web resolution. As far as affecting the SEO of any site these images are on, image size affects how fast a page will load, and that DOES impact your SEO.

Comment: Thanks illbzo1, check out this video from Google and tell me what you think. Looks like larger images may do better in regards to best matching what the user is looking for - http://youtu.be/h2Zaj0CAUoU